# Ubuntu One is quite slow

Tags: ubuntu-one, nautilus, sync

Ubuntu One is quite slow. Changed files are rather fast displayed in the web-interface, but not on my second computer's Ubuntu-One folder. Does anyone know howto speed-up things?

Answer (score 1):

The speed of syncing between computers may vary based on the size of your files, how active our servers are, and how fast a connection you have. I have a fast connection and files pretty much begin sync within a few moments.

Lets say Computer A is one computer and Computer B is the one that is not syncing.
Is there any activity in the logs of Computer B? Is is connected, receiving messages from Ubuntu One?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Where do I find those logs? Both computers are connected.

Comment: The log files in Ubuntu are in ~/.cache/ubuntuone/logs